# Removing enter from every line of file

Tags: python, text, operating-system

im new to Python. Is there a way to change the content of the file to the way i want it?
This is my txt file

```
work
money
apple
dog
```

and i want this to change to

```
work money apple dog
```

I don't know how to put them in one line, rest is clear for me
My code for now

```
fn = 'settings.txt'
f = open(fn)
for line in f:
  f.join(f.read().splitlines())
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You read the items, line by line, and concatenate them.  Use `+` or `join`.  Write the resulting string.

Comment: I've opened the file, and now I'm stuck at for line in f(which is the opened file)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please also submit some code what you tried as @Prune suggests. You could take a look at [how to create a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok, i've edited my post

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```py
with open('file_path') as f_1:
    res_str = ' '.join(f_1.read().splitlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str` `strip()` method to remove spaces and line feed at the end of the line.

so, probably something along the lines of:

```
words = list()

with open("my_file_path") as file:
    for line in file:
        words.append(line.strip())

result = " ".join(words)
```

Using a generator expression:

```
with open("my_file_path") as file:
    result = " ".join(line.strip() for line in file)
```

Comment: It works, but @AlexanderCécile solution is better :)

Comment: @Eraw awn <3 I appreciate the gesture, but I actually disagree! It depends on what OP does with the resulting string.